# How to use proteced function in an expl3 conditional predicate?

Tags: expl3, latex3

I want to define a conditional function `\if_is_int:n(TF)` to test if the parameter is an integer, so I wrote:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \ExplSyntaxOn
    \prg_new_conditional:Npnn \my_cond:n #1 { p, T, F, TF } 
      {     
        \regex_match:nnTF { [\+\-]?\d+ } { #1 }
          { \prg_return_true: }
          { \prg_return_false: } 
      }
    \bool_if:nTF { \my_cond_p:n { hello } } { true } { false } % missing number
    % \my_cond:nTF { hello } { true } { false } % output false
  \ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

After pdflatex, it returns

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \group_begin: 
l.11     \bool_if:nTF { \my_cond_p:n { hello } }
                                                 { true } { false } % missin.
```

If I use `\if_is_int:nTF` directly, it works fine.

I found this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/630105/180617 which says:

> Boolean expressions in expl3 work by expansion, and so they can only contain expandable functions in their implementation: those are marked with a star in interface3.pdf

So I can't use `\regex_match:nnTF` in `\prg_new_conditional:Npnn` since `\regex_match:nnTF` is `\protected`?

[image]

However, if I use `\prg_new_protected_conditional:Npnn`, I can't use the `p` parameter that I need.

Is there any way to use `\if_is_int_p:n` to test "if is integer" in a `\bool_if:nTF` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use any non-expandable functions in defining a predicate, ad the linked answer suggests. That means that you cannot use for example *any* regex functions in a predicate. Instead, you will need to rework your approach to use a `TF` branch - this may mean you have to be a bit more 'repetitive'.